# How to convert DM-script files (*.s) into a plugin file (*.gtk)

Tags: dm-script

I have written some DM-script files (*.s), and thus I would like to convert (compile?) them into plugin files (*.gtk). In this case, should I prepare some kind of compiler and Gatan Software Development Kit (SDK) package, or others? If there is a good way, please teach the procedure in detail. I will be really grateful, if you share some wisdom to create *.gtk files.

Comment: The SDK is only used for developers wanting to write C++ code and compile it as a plugin for DigitalMicrograph. (i.e. create a `*.dll` file which loads as plugin.) This is a completely different story than writing scripts and installing them as a script package. For the other question, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.GTK files are not *compiled* - you will not gain any speed benefit of having them in a .gtk (or .gt1, .gt2 ) file. They are only *packed* into those files for convenience of sharing and distributing them easily without sharing source code.

That said, the way to "pack" scripts into those files is to use a script-command itself, i.e. write a script which build these files from a set of .s files on the hard drive.

> The command to add a script-file to a script package is `AddScriptFileToPackage` with the syntax:

```
void AddScriptFileToPackage( String file_path, String packageName, Number packageLevel, String packageLocation, String command_name, String menu_name, String sub_menu_name, Boolean isLibrary )
void AddScriptFileToPackage( String file_path, String packageName, Number packageLevel, String command_name, String menu_name, String sub_menu_name, Boolean isLibrary )
```

> The command to add a script (string) to a script package is `AddScriptToPackage` with the syntax:

```
void AddScriptToPackage( String script, String packageName, Number packageLevel, String packageLocation, String command_name, String menu_name, String sub_menu_name, Boolean isLibrary )
void AddScriptToPackage( String script, String packageName, Number packageLevel, String command_name, String menu_name, String sub_menu_name, Boolean isLibrary )
```

> The paramters in the two commands are:

[image: Parameters of AddScriptFileToPackage]

Note, that the created plugin-file will by default appear in the `user_plugin` location:

`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Gatan\Plugins`

The second syntax allows specifying the path, where the `packageLocation` parameter might be any of the names also accepted in the command `GetApplicationDirectory`, most often either being `user_plugin` (see above) or just `plugin` referring to the current run DigitalMicrograph.exe relative plugin folder, i.e.

`.\Plugins` relative to where the DigitalMicrograph.exe sits, typically
`C:\Program Files\Gatan\Plugins\`

Note, that one can append scripts to an existing file, but can not "unistall" one from it. In that case, one has to delete the file and re-create it anew.
Also, if an error occurs in the to-be-added scripts, they will not install correctly and you might need to start over.

The F1 help documentation (of later GMS versions) has an example script showing how to typically use the command:
[image: F1 help]

---

The difference between *libary* and *command* install is the same as when using the File-Menu command to "install a script". A library usually is a set of methods (or classes) which, when installed, remain available and in memory. The *command* installs a script as a menu-command to the UI. i.e. selecting the menu executes the scirpt (once). 
While the "File/Install Script" install things into the general prefereces-file of DigitalMicrograph, the commands above create separate .gtk files which load on startup if found in the plugins-folder. Any code that is installed as "library" is run once on startup.

Comment: I'm really sorry for my delayed response. I greatly appreciate your detailed advices and explanations. As you mentioned, I misunderstood that *.gtk files are compiled ones of *.s script files. I will try to create *.gtk files by the way you showed me. Thank you very much again.

Comment: @kachigusa No worries. The nice thing about the StackOverflow format is, that everybody can use it at his/her own pace. Glad the answer solved your question.