# Where to get detailed documentation on dm script functions

Tags: documentation, dm-script

How do I get function definitions with detailed descriptions?

The help section (F1) tells which functions exist but the descriptions are not detailed enough for me. They do not specify optional arguments nor do they explain parameters or what functions do in perticular:

> ```
> void ComponentSetFillMode( Component comp, Number mode )
> ```
>
> Sets the fill mode of the image document component.

The documentation does not tell which `mode` is allowed and what each `mode` does.

> ```
> void TextAnnotationSetFixedPoint( Component comp, Number x, Number y )
> ```
>
> Sets the fixed point of the text annotation.

Again there is no information about what the "fixed point" is. Also by trying around I could not figure out what this does.

> ```
> Number TagGroupGetTagSize( TagGroup tagGroup, Number index )
> ```
>
> Gets the size of the tag.

Another example where it took me hours with trying different (self generated) examples until I had a rough idea what the "size" is (or better is not) and how to use it for my purpose.

The help section includes a summary of all functions but without any parameters insufficient descriptions. I have other sources too but they also do not cover everything and they are not intended to be documentations. Googling around only showed me a [function summary](http://digitalmicrograph-scripting.tavernmaker.de/other%20resources/Old-DMHelp/AllFunctions.html) (which seems to be outdated) and sometimes pictures like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53140218/5934316) (picture 1) which seem very interesting.

So is there any way to get detailed function definitions? Is there a (inofficial) more detailed documentation?

[image]

Picture 1 - An image that looks like a detailed documentation from taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53140218/5934316)

Comment: The particular image stems from some DM-scripting course material from a Gatan scripting workshop held in Tokyo 2015.

Comment: Part of the 'problem' of the F1 help documentation is, that it contains 'all' commands or at least many commands that have been historically added by developers for internal use but are not really meant for the general user. Historically, DM-scripting was to a large extend a tool for service engineers in an ever-changing software environment. This explains both the flexibility of the language, but also its often haphazard approach to documentation or obsolete commands, parameters etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The not very satisfying answer is, that the most detailed official documentation *is* the F1 help documentation. While it has improved over the years, it is still not perfect.

There are a few user-based additional resources on the web, but they all suffer from their own 'incompleteness'.

This is one of the main reasons, a community base effort like StackOverflow here is of so immense importance.